# Running Outlook through win32com.client using Task Scheduler

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task (python script) in Windows Task Scheduler that checks a specific email every morning and download the attachment. I have been using this task for about a month it never broke. But today I found that the task can't establish connection to Outlook with win32com.client.

When the task runs, it will bring up the command line and then turned off automatically and nothing really runs. It works well if I directly run the python script inside the command line though.

Below is the line where the python script stuck if running in task scheduler.

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a workaround, you are free to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any other third-party wrappers around this API such as Redemption. Also you may consider using EWS if you deal with Exchange only, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by unclicking "with highest privilege" in task scheduler. Also, I added a chunk of code in front of my python script so that it clears the python temp folder every time of running.